# 'found' in 'car found in river' vs 'car been found in river'?

Tags: word-choice

What's difference of the 'found' between **'car found in river'** vs **'car been found in river'**?

Are they all verb? and what's difference?

as I checked in Collins Dictionary, 'found' seems didn't have adjective part of speech. so, what's the 'found' in 'car found in river' represented?

thanks.

Comment: **Found** is the past participle of the verb **to find**. The second example (in the question title) works if the sentence is extended, such as to the question "Has a car been found in the river?" The first "car found in river" is the type of "sentence" used in a newspaper headline.

Comment: "Car found in river" is a news headline style.

Comment: @Lambie right, as I commented just above.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks, very interesting clue. Do you know where can I find any reference of the Title English vs Written English?

Comment: Here is [one reference](http://www.englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/8-grammar-rules-writing-newspaper-headlines/)

Comment: thanks @WeatherVane I would like to choose your comment as an answer, would you please make your first comment as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found** is the past participle of the verb **to find**.

The second phrase in the question title works if the sentence is extended, such as the question

> Has a car been found in the river?

The first phrase in the title

> Car found in river

is like the abbreviated "sentence" used in newspaper headlines.